# OIDC authentication with Express using Passport

Tags: express, passport.js, openid

I'm trying to connect through a Custom SSO (using OIDC).
I receive a JWT_Token with a nbf time 16 seconds in the future. I suspect that the SSO server and my server is not synchronized on same time.
How I could manage this?
Here my auth process.

```
 router.get('/oidc/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
    const subdomain = req.app.settings.subDomain();
    passport.authenticate('oidc', { scope: 'openid email profile', state: subdomain })(req, res, next);
  });


  router.get('/oidc/signin', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('oidc', {
      failureRedirect: '/'
    }, function (err, user, info) {
      if (err) {
        logger.error('Error during authentication:');
        logger.error(err)
        return res.redirect('/failure');
      }
      if (!user) {
        logger.error('Authentication failed:');
        logger.error(info);
        return res.redirect('/');
      }
      req.logIn(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error('Error during login:');
          logger.error(err);
          return res.redirect('/failure');
        }
        return home.openid.callback(req, res, next);
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

Here the token that I receive

```
 {
  now: 1683984532,
  tolerance: 0,
  nbf: 1683984548,
  jwt: 'token_string',
  name: 'RPError',
  level: 'error',
  timestamp: '2023-05-13T13:28:52.301Z'
  }
```

If i set my dev computer time to 1 minute later, it's working well, I'm able to connect through the SSO... But in prod, i would not like to set the time to a 1 minute later time...

[EDIT] I found how to resolve the problem. I add the custom.clock_tolerance to the config like this.

```
var client = new oidcIssuer.Client({
                client_id: config.openIdConnect.clientId,
                client_secret: config.openIdConnect.clientSecret,
                redirect_uris: [config.openIdConnect.redirectUri],
                response_types: ['code'],
            });
            client[custom.clock_tolerance] = 60;
```